# python BaseHTTPRequestHandler instance error

Tags: python, class

I try to create a class instance of BaseHTTPRequestHandler but I have an error message.
Here is what I did :

```
>>> from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
>>> obj=BaseHTTPRequestHandler()
>>> obj.send_response(200)
```

I got :

```
>>> obj=BaseHTTPRequestHandler()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Could you please give me some advice

Comment: You should be giving `4` arguments to `BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__`.  The first is `self`, which is passed implicitly.  The other three you need to supply.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of BaseHTTPRequestHandler is as follows

```
class BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address, server)
```

The problem is that youre not providing the values it needs

You can check https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#module-BaseHTTPServer for detailed info on what it requires exactly.

As @iCodez commented, `self` counts as 1 of the 4 needed arguments, but is passed implicitly, so you just need to pass the other 3